# Integrate a existing free or paid version control into System

Tags: .net, version-control

I am writing a system that allows users to modify document templates as such I want them to be able to checkout, branch, check-in, and promote (merge) these documents while they are working on them or getting them approved. this includes some metadata about these templates. I don't want to go and make one from scratch because there are so many out there. is there anything that would be good to integrate that can deploy the repo as a sql db and has a .net Nuget package to interact with the database.

Comment: The obvious answer is Git, using libgit2 and its .Net bindings, but you can't store the repo as an SQL database.  Most version control systems won't meet that criterion.

Comment: cool that's exactly what I am talking about. Please put this as the answer and I'll Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious choice here is Git.  There's a shared library implementation called libgit2, which has bindings to a variety of languages, include the .NET platform.  It is a bit lower level than the command line Git implementation, but it should meet your needs.  Note, however, that it doesn't include the ability to store in an SQL database; it only stores data in the file system as a normal Git repository.